# Splitting non-continuous sized matrix in vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm writing an piece of software within Matlab. Here, the user can define a dimension say 3.

This dimension is subsequently the number of iterations of a for loop. Within this loop, I construct a matrix to store the results which are generated during every iteration. So, the data of every iteration is stored in a row of a matrix.

Therefore, the size of the matrix depends on the size of the loop and thus the user input.

Now, I want to separate each row of this matrix (cl_matrix) and create separate vectors for every row automatically.  How would one go on about? I am stuck here...

So far I have:

```
Angle = [1 7 15];
for i = 1:length(Angle)
    %% do some calculations here %%
    cl_matrix(i,:) = A.data(:,7);
end
```

I want to automate this based on the length of Angle:

```
length(Angle)
cl_1 = cl_matrix(1,:);
cl_7 = cl_matrix(2,:);
cl_15= cl_matrix(3,:);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking. Why would the matrix be non-continuous?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's very bad practice and will only lead to more headaches in the future. You have a perfectly usable matrix with sensible indices: I suggest you use that.

Comment: Since the size changes, it depends on the length of ''Angle''. Therefore, the amount of output vectors change

Comment: How about using a cell array? I agree with beaker, that this will probably lead to other problems in the future. All I could think of, if you really need that, is to use `eval`. But that would be both slow and ugly.

Comment: Because I want to interpolate the data in 3 dimensions, it makes it easier to split the vectors.

Comment: @BalrajBoyal When the length of `Angle` changes, the length of `cl_matrix` will change too. Please show us your interpolation code, if that's what you're worried about. I fail to see why `cl_457` is easier than `cl_matrix(42,:)`. Particularly when your next question will likely be "how do I iterate over all of these variable names, `c1_1`, `c1_7`...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to dynamically generate in the `workspace` variables variables whos name is built by aggregating string and numeric values (as in your question) is to use the `eval` function.

Nevertheless, `eval` is only one character far from "evil", seductive as it is and dangerous as it is as well.

A possible compromise between directly working with the `cl_matrix` and generating the set of array `cl_1`, `cl_7` and `cl_15` could be creating a `structure` whos `fields` are [dynamically generated](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

You can actually generate a `struct` whos field are `cl_1`, `cl_7` and `cl_15` this way:

```
cl_struct.(['cl_' num2str(Angle(i))])=cl_matrix(i,:)
```

(you might notice the field name, e. g. `cl_1`, is generated in the same way you could generate it by using `eval`).

Using this approach offers a remarkable advantage with respect to the generation of the arrays by using `eval`: you can access to the `field` od the `struct` (that is to their content) even not knowing their names.

In the following you can find a modified version of your script in which this approach has been implemented.

The script generate two structs:

- the first one, `cl_struct_same_length` is used to store the rows of the `cl_matrix`
- thesecond one, `cl_struct_different_length` is used to store arrays of different length

In the script there are examples on how to access to the fileds (that is the arrays) to perform some calculations (in the example, to evaluate the `mean` of each of then).

You can access to the struct fields by using the functions:

- `getfield` to get the values stored in it
- `fieldnames` to get the names (dynamically generated) of the field

**Updated script**

```
Angle = [1 7 15];
for i = 1:length(Angle)
   % do some calculations here %%
% % %   cl_matrix(i,:) = A.data(:,7);
   % Populate cl_matrix
    cl_matrix(i,:) = randi(10,1,10)*Angle(i);
    % Create a struct with dinamic filed names
    cl_struct_same_length.(['cl_' num2str(Angle(i))])=cl_matrix(i,:)
    cl_struct_different_length.(['cl_' num2str(Angle(i))])=randi(10,1,Angle(i))
end
% Use "fieldnames" to get the names of the dinamically generated struct's field
cl_fields=fieldnames(cl_struct_same_length)
% Loop through the struct's fileds to perform some calculation on the
% stored values
for i=1:length(cl_fields)
   cl_means(i)=mean(cl_struct_same_length.(cl_fields{i}))
end
% Assign the value stored in a struct's field to a variable
row_2_of_cl_matrix=getfield(cl_struct_different_length,(['cl_' num2str(Angle(2))]))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice analogy between `eval` and "evil"