# How to set a desired name in MATLAB from words and numbers extracted from data?

Tags: string, matlab, filenames

I want to extract three number from different column of my dataset and set these numbers along with some words to be the name of my variable in workspace, and then assign a matrix to this variable. For instance:

```
data=dataset{:,:,5}; 
FID=data(1,14);
VID=data(1,1);
PID=data(1,15)
```

Here I extracted three number from different column of a matrix in dataset:
FID=4  ,  VID=8  ,  PID=12

Now, I want to create a variable in the workspace using these three numbers besides three words with underline between them, such as: A4_B8_C12

and then assign a matrix to this variable:

```
A4_B8_C12=dataset{:,:,5};
```

Since, my dataset is a cell array and contains 2169 matrices, I'm writing a code to extract the three numbers from desired matrix and use them along with desired words to create several matrices.

How can I do that?

Comment: HO WMANY VARIABLES YOU WANT TO HAVE?!?!?! 6000??? NOO DONT DO THAT!

Comment: to say that in a calmly fashion: you generally do not want to have huge number of variables, you can use a cell Array or a Matrix to store your fields as 1 variable with varying sub elements.

Comment: @GameOfThrows or even a struct with a dynamic field name.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HXTK4BE.jpg

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084043/splitting-non-continuous-sized-matrix-in-vectors), which asks for more or less the same. As also suggested by @AndrasDeak the solution there was to create a structure with dynamic field names. Of course, a cell array or matrix, as suggested by GameOfThrows are equally applicable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you have cell arrays, structs and arrays, this is not a good practice. This is against the philosophy of using arrays. But any way if you want continue this way of programming you can use the following code:

```
for i=1:5
    data=dataset{:,:,i}; 
    FID=data(1,14);
    VID=data(1,1);
    PID=data(1,15);
    eval(sprintf('A%d_B%d_C%d=data;',FID,VID,CID));
end
```

Using evalf is a kind of programming which can be used for self modifying codes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Well, I have no choice but to use this code. Since, my dataset contains many matrix data, and I want to separate several matrices based on some criteria, and doing so require to use a code like this.

Comment: Nooooo. Don't teach this. There's (almost) always another way:(

Comment: This. Is. So. So. So. Wrong.